Vite npm run dev on laravel rtying to access resoures folder
I have a simple docker-compose file
version: '3.4'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "5173:5173"
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Moscow
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./files/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
            - ./files/src:/var/www/crm
        links:
            - "php:php"
            

    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
            - TZ=Europe/Moscow
        volumes:
            - ./files/db:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker/mysql/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        # command: --sql_mode='NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'  #STRICT_TRANS_TABLES


    php:
        build: ./docker/php
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Moscow
        volumes:
            - ./files/src:/var/www/crm
        links:
            - mysql


    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - 8091:80
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Moscow
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        links:
            - mysql:db

installed Laravel 11 and breeze
when I run npm run build  vite compiles app.js and app.css successfully
but when I try to run npm run dev  it starts but on the browser console I got errors
GET http://lara.crm/resources/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
dashboard:15 
GET http://lara.crm/@vite/client net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
dashboard:15 
GET http://lara.crm/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

it tries to get files from the resources folder which is unavailable
(in nginx I have root lara.crm/public)
here is Vite config
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: 'lara.crm',
        port: 80,
    },
    build: {
        // outDir: './public/build', // Adjust this path according to your setup
    },

});


how to make npm run dev  work?
Thanks
I suppose open access to resources folder is not a correct way to resolve a problem.
Probably npm run dev should work "out of box" if I use artisan serve  server but how to make it work on custom nginx+php-fpm server?
